NMOS MOSFET with VGS of 20V getting too hot on PWM of 700Hz
There are three identical circuits connected in parallel to the source each with a PWM source received an STM board, when powering on the 24V source my mosfet gets really hot, but only with a high duty cycle. Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong?


Please upload a screenshot of your entire schematic instead of a photo of your screen with a portion of it.

You are subjecting your MOSFET gate-source to 24 V. It's not going to like that for very long.

You are doing two things wrong.
Firstly you have the N channel MOSFET connected as a source follower hence, you will never provide sufficient gate-drive voltage to adequately turn the device on when the average voltage at the output of the buck regulator (across C1) is high. This of course is worse when the duty cycle is high. You also have maximum load current when the duty cycle is high thus compounding the issue of heat generated (R2 is 10 Ω). This is the wrong way to use an N channel device in a buck regulator (something we've seen a few times on this site).
Secondly, the BSP89 has a maximum gate-source rating of +/- 20 volts yet, when deactivated this is likely to be close to being exceeded in the negative range of the limits. Poor design is the culprit and you should simulate your circuit to see what I mean.
